# How to convert old .NET OutputCaching to .NET 8.0 OutputCaching?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, server-side, .net-8.0

The below code worked perfectly for my .NET 4.5 website:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 60, NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)] // 1 MINUTE CACHE
public JsonResult MyController(...)
{ ... }
```

When trying to use this for my brand new .NET 8.0 project and I immediately get errors for `VaryByParam` and `Location`. Maybe the two most important settings. I especially want the cache to be server side because I have many devices requesting data and if one already have I just want the other devices to get the same reply without generating a request further down the chain.

I have tried making adjustments like this

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, NoStore = true, VaryByQueryKeys = ["*"])]
```

But it doesn't work and it certainly doesn't tell the server to cache this on the server side which I need it to do.

How can I convert the old type .NET OutputCaching to the new .NET 8.0 OutputCaching with the same attributes, especially with server side caching?

Comment: Have you added  `app.UseOutputCache();` somewhere at the start of the middleware pipeline (for example before the explicit `app.UseRouting();` call)?

Comment: @GuruStron No, I only added builder.Services.AddOutputCache();. I will try this.

Comment: Also `NoStore = true` means that _"when set to `true` the response won't be cached."_ so change it to `false`.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it works :-). Strange though that NoStore = true was set for my old .NET 4.5 and there it worked.

Comment: I would guess that it had different meaning back then. Note that output caching was added only relatively recently to ASP.NET Core and represents only server-side caching. Added as answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`OutputCacheAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/36c976723fd0b55dad80f1ff32e665800ea4a021/src/Middleware/OutputCaching/src/OutputCacheAttribute.cs#L36) has [`NoStore`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/36c976723fd0b55dad80f1ff32e665800ea4a021/src/Middleware/OutputCaching/src/OutputCacheAttribute.cs#L36) defined as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the value which determines whether the response should be cached or not.
/// When set to <see langword="true"/>, the response won't be cached.
/// </summary>
public bool NoStore
{
    get => _noCache ?? false;
    init => _noCache = value;
}
```

So if you set it to `true` it will actually disable the output caching.

Also do not forget to call `UseOutputCache()` at appropriate place - see the [sample @github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/36c976723fd0b55dad80f1ff32e665800ea4a021/src/Middleware/OutputCaching/samples/OutputCachingSample/Startup.cs#L20):

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseOutputCache();
```

Note that output caching was added only relatively recently to the ASP.NET Core (in [the 7th version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0#output-caching-middleware)). Also note that it represents server-side caching unlike the [`OutputCacheAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) based on available options for `Location` (note that new one supports [cache revalidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cache-revalidation)).